# UWP CommandBar SecondaryCommand collides with AppBarButton Flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have an `AppBarButton` which displays a `MenuFlyout` when clicked. And that button is in a `CommandBar`.

However, after it is collapsed to the `MoreButton` due to the overflow, the AppBarButton's Flyout becomes hard to click. This is because the `MoreButton` creates a `Flyout` and the second click on the `AppBarButton` hides both `Flyout`.

So how can I resolve this problem?

Preferably, I want the `AppBarButton` to be converted to a `MenuFlyoutSubItem`, but I don't know how to do that.

Another problem about the overflow is that, although I have set the `CornerRadius` of the `MoreButton` to be 20 in its style, it is still a rectangle indeed. What is wrong?

```
<Button
    x:Name="MoreButton"
    Grid.Column="1"
    MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}"
    Padding="{ThemeResource CommandBarMoreButtonMargin}"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Control.IsTemplateKeyTipTarget="True"
    CornerRadius="20"
    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
    IsAccessKeyScope="True"
    Style="{StaticResource EllipsisButton}"
    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CommandBarTemplateSettings.EffectiveOverflowButtonVisibility}">
    <FontIcon
        x:Name="EllipsisIcon"
        Height="{ThemeResource AppBarExpandButtonCircleDiameter}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
        FontSize="20"
        Glyph="&#xE10C;" />
</Button>
```

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I know that should be avoided so I am thinking is there a way to convert it to a MenuFlyoutSubItem when it is collapsed? And do you have an answer for my second question?

Comment: Please copy the default the style and remove `X:Key` value <Style TargetType="CommandBar">.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Where is `<Style TargetType="CommandBar">`? And this is almost the default style just with my minor modifications.

Comment: I mean, you need custom `CommandBar`  style.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes I am customizing it. And the customization for MoreButton is not working.

Comment: Could you show me how to custom CommandBar  style?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199225/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-seaky-luo).

Comment: For costuming the more button style you need copy the complete `CommandBar` style.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Sorry I was working on the project. I have joined the chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `Flyout` light dismiss behavior and it's by design, for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/flyouts#light-dismiss-behavior). For your requirement please avoid put the  `MenuFlyout` in to MoreButton's flyout. I think you could place all the items in the `SecondaryCommands` and use `AppBarSeparator` to split into different areas.

```
<CommandBar Background="Transparent" IsOpen="False" DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
    <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="ReShare" Label="Share"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit"/>
    <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Label="Settings">
            <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="S" />
            </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Button 1">
            <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="N" />
            </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Button 2">
            <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Delete" />
            </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarSeparator />
        <AppBarButton Icon="FontDecrease" Label="Button 3">
            <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="Subtract" />
            </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Icon="FontIncrease" Label="Button 4">
            <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="Add" />
            </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
```

[image]

> Another problem about the overflow is that, although I have set the CornerRadius of the MoreButton to be 20 in its style, it is still a rectangle indeed. What is wrong

I used the following style and the `CornerRadius` works well

```
<Style TargetType="CommandBar">
.....
<Button x:Name="MoreButton"
        Background="Red"
        CornerRadius="20"
Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
Style="{StaticResource EllipsisButtonRevealStyle}"
Padding="{ThemeResource CommandBarMoreButtonMargin}"
MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
Grid.Column="1"
Control.IsTemplateKeyTipTarget="True"
IsAccessKeyScope="True"
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CommandBarTemplateSettings.EffectiveOverflowButtonVisibility}">
    <FontIcon x:Name="EllipsisIcon"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
        FontSize="20"
        Glyph="&#xE10C;"
        Height="{ThemeResource AppBarExpandButtonCircleDiameter}" />
</Button>

.....

</Style>
```

[image]

**Update**

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="20">
    <Button
        x:Name="MoreButton"
        MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}"
        Padding="{ThemeResource CommandBarMoreButtonMargin}"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Control.IsTemplateKeyTipTarget="True"
        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
        IsAccessKeyScope="True"
        Style="{StaticResource EllipsisButton}"
        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CommandBarTemplateSettings.EffectiveOverflowButtonVisibility}"
        >
        <FontIcon
            x:Name="EllipsisIcon"
            Height="{ThemeResource AppBarExpandButtonCircleDiameter}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
            FontSize="20"
            Glyph="&#xE10C;"
            />
    </Button>
</Border>
```

Comment: I prefer `MenuFlyout` to `CommandBar.SecondaryCommands`. I was having a bad time using `ToggleAppBarButton` in it.

Comment: @SeakyLuose, I run your code, I could reproduce your issue, it may collide with button style, Currently we have a workaround that add the border for the more button. For more please refer the above update .

Comment: Thank you! Still for the first question, is it possible to add controls other than `AppBarButton` to the `CommandBar`?

Comment: Available element for `CommandBar ` content should be realize `ICommandBarElement` interface. You could custom your control that inherit `ICommandBarElement`.